# SavedInstance of multiple customViews inside one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have multiple instances of the same CustomView inside one fragment.
I implemented savedInstance for this CustomView but the problem is since there are multiple instances of this CustomView, `savedInstance` of the last one, overrides them all.

for example, if there are 3 instances of this CustomView which has a recyclerview inside, If I scroll the last one, it applies to them all. because i'm using key value pairs and the key is the same for all of them. (I can change the key to differ for each one but I think there is a better way)

Here is the code for savedInstance saving and restoring inside my CustomView:

```
 @Nullable
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(SavedInstanceKey.SUPERSTATE.name(), super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putParcelable(SavedInstanceKey.RECYCLERVIEW.name(), recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState()); // ... save stuff
    return bundle;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (state instanceof Bundle) // implicit null check
    {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        this.recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(SavedInstanceKey.RECYCLERVIEW.name())); // ... load stuff
        state = bundle.getParcelable(SavedInstanceKey.SUPERSTATE.name());
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

and here is my fragment's OnCreateView:

```
  @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist, container, false);

    final GridListView gv_new = view.findViewById(R.id.gridlist_new_songs);
    final GridListView gv_best = view.findViewById(R.id.gridlist_best);
    final GridListView gv_singles = view.findViewById(R.id.gridlist_singles);
    final GridListView gv_feats = view.findViewById(R.id.gridlist_feats);
    final RecyclerView rc_albums = view.findViewById(R.id.rcview_album);

    if(!alreadyInitialized) {
        alreadyInitialized = true;
        apiService = new ApiService(getContext());
        try {
            artistID = getArguments().getString(KeyIntent.ARTIST.name());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: Artist Fragment doesnt have args.\t", e);
        }

        apiService.getArtist(artistID, new ApiService.OnArtistReceived() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Artist artist) {
                ArtistFragment.this.artist=artist;
                setArtistToViews(artist, view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error on receiving artist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        apiService.getNewSongs(artistID, new ApiService.OnSongsReceived() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Song> songs) {
                ArtistFragment.this.newSongs=songs;
                List<GridListable> gridListables = new ArrayList<>();
                gridListables.addAll(songs);
                gv_new.load(gridListables, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(ApiService.ApiResponse response) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error on receiving artist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        apiService.getBestSongs(artistID, new ApiService.OnSongsReceived() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Song> songs) {
                ArtistFragment.this.bestSongs=songs;
                List<GridListable> gridListables = new ArrayList<>();
                gridListables.addAll(songs);
                gv_best.load(gridListables, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(ApiService.ApiResponse response) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error on receiving artist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        apiService.getSingleSongs(artistID, new ApiService.OnSongsReceived() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Song> songs) {
                ArtistFragment.this.singleSongs=songs;
                List<GridListable> gridListables = new ArrayList<>();
                gridListables.addAll(songs);
                gv_singles.load(gridListables, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(ApiService.ApiResponse response) {

            }
        });

        apiService.getFeats(artistID, new ApiService.OnSongsReceived() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Song> songs) {
                ArtistFragment.this.feats=songs;
                List<GridListable> gridListables = new ArrayList<>();
                gridListables.addAll(songs);
                gv_feats.load(gridListables, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(ApiService.ApiResponse response) {

            }
        });

        apiService.getAlbums(artistID, new ApiService.OnAlbumsReceived() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Album> albums) {
                ArtistFragment.this.albums=albums;

                List<Projective> projectives = new ArrayList<>();
                projectives.addAll(albums);
                rc_albums.setAdapter(new AlbumAdapter(getContext(), projectives));
                rc_albums.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail(ApiService.ApiResponse response) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Loading albums failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }else {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: Fragment already initialized, restoring from existing artist");
        setArtistToViews(artist,view);
        gv_new.load(new ArrayList<>(newSongs),1);
        gv_best.load(new ArrayList<>(bestSongs),1);
        gv_singles.load(new ArrayList<>(singleSongs),1);
        gv_feats.load(new ArrayList<>(feats),1);
        rc_albums.setAdapter(new AlbumAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<>(albums)));
        rc_albums.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the Keys that you use for your Bundles. All your instances of the custom view use the same `SavedInstanceKey.SUPERSTATE.name()`.

You could try to have the Fragment pass a different key to each of the custom views (BEST, NEW...). This way, each of your GridView has its own unique key to use in the saveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState methods.

Comment: I tried it but it still holds the last item's state. I debugged it and the key-value pair is working and keys are different but the result is wrong and all of them are scrolled where the last one was